# How to set the log level in Grails 4

Tags: spring-boot, grails, logback, grails-4

In my Grails 4 app, `log.info("log message")` doesn't show log, but `log.error("log message")` does.

How do I change the log level from `error` to `info` in Grails 4?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Option 1**

All I needed to do was update the `application.yml` file and added the following to the bottom

```
logging:
    level:
        root: INFO
```

You can also set a single the log level for a single package:

```
logging:
    level:
        packageName: INFO
```

**Option 2**

Since Grails 4 is based on Spring Boot, I ended up just setting the appropriate environment variable, i.e. `logging.level.root=INFO` or `logging.level.com.mycompany.mypackage=INFO` which I did in intellij by editing my run configuration (see below).  This way, I can set the logging level differently when I deploy it.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You want to edit grails-app/conf/logback.groovy.  Below is what the default file looks like for Grails 4.0.1.

```
import grails.util.BuildSettings
import grails.util.Environment
import org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.ColorConverter
import org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.WhitespaceThrowableProxyConverter

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

conversionRule 'clr', ColorConverter
conversionRule 'wex', WhitespaceThrowableProxyConverter

// See http://logback.qos.ch/manual/groovy.html for details on configuration
appender('STDOUT', ConsoleAppender) {
    encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
        charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8

        pattern =
                '%clr(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}){faint} ' + // Date
                        '%clr(%5p) ' + // Log level
                        '%clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} ' + // Thread
                        '%clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} ' + // Logger
                        '%m%n%wex' // Message
    }
}

def targetDir = BuildSettings.TARGET_DIR
if (Environment.isDevelopmentMode() && targetDir != null) {
    appender("FULL_STACKTRACE", FileAppender) {
        file = "${targetDir}/stacktrace.log"
        append = true
        encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
            charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8
            pattern = "%level %logger - %msg%n"
        }
    }
    logger("StackTrace", ERROR, ['FULL_STACKTRACE'], false)
}
root(ERROR, ['STDOUT'])
```

The specific change depends on what you really want to do.  For example, if you have a controller named `demo.SomeController` and you want to set its log level to `INFO`, you could add something like this:

```
logger 'demo.SomeController', INFO, ['STDOUT'], false
```

See http://logback.qos.ch/manual/groovy.html for the full config reference.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I added  
logger ("org.hibernate.orm.deprecation", ERROR, ["STDOUT"])
root(ERROR, ['STDOUT'])
but I still get warning level logs from org.hibernate.orm.deprecation. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Simple Way:

Update/Replace your `grails-app/conf/logback.groovy` with following code:

```
    import ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder

appender("FILE", RollingFileAppender) {
    file = "logs/FILE-NAME.log"
    rollingPolicy(TimeBasedRollingPolicy) {
        fileNamePattern = "logs/FILE-NAME-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
        maxHistory = 30
    }
    encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
        pattern = "%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n"
    }

}
root(INFO, ["FILE"])
```

Above solution shows logger level to `INFO`

You can refer [this](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/groovy.html) more details and all log levels.

Hope this will helps you.